# Error in the on_message function of a discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

The whole bot works except the send_message function I created.

```
@client.event
async def send_winners():
    img = Image.open("placement_temp.jpg")

    send_winners = json.loads(open('send_message.json').read())

    if send_winners == True:
        channel = 686026687145705505 #648365930639785985   


        await message.channel.send(channel, "<@&684816171316412458> And the Winners of this week are:", img)  # Error happening here
        send_winners = no
        with open("winner_send.json", "w") as fp:
            json.dump(send_winners, fp)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Comment: can you include the full error message?

Comment: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: can you include the full stack trace included with the error?

Comment: Also you might want to try putting the channel in quotes: `channel = "686026687145705505"`

Comment: File "C:\Users\agweb\Documents\GitHub\TrophyBot\TrophyBot.py", line 223, in <module>
    client.loop.create_task(send_winners(message))
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: looks like the error is in whatever function is calling send_winners

Comment: Can you post the full source(including line 223)? Also, your code appears to have other syntax errors(`send_winners = no`)

Comment: That is the full stack     Line 223 is client.loop.create_task(send_winners(message))

Comment: Also I fixed send_winners = no while I was waiting for a reply

Comment: You use `await message.channel.send()` but you haven't defined `message` anywhere in the function, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@client.event
async def send_winners(message):

    send_winners = json.loads(open('send_message.json').read())

    if send_winners == True:
        channel = 686026687145705505 #648365930639785985   


        await message.channel.send(channel, "<@&684816171316412458> And the Winners of this week are:", Image.open("placement_temp.jpg"))  # Error happening here
        send_winners = no
        with open("winner_send.json", "w") as fp:
            json.dump(send_winners, fp)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Comment: But message is still undefined

Comment: Try this then ```@client.event
async def send_winners(message):

    send_winners = json.loads(open('send_message.json').read())

    if send_winners == True:
        channel = 686026687145705505 #648365930639785985   


        await message.channel.send(channel, "<@&684816171316412458> And the Winners of this week are:", Image.open("placement_temp.jpg"))  # Error happening here
        send_winners = no
        with open("winner_send.json", "w") as fp:
            json.dump(send_winners, fp)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)```